# Weblogic server could not start and could not configure domain

Tags: oracle, weblogic, osb

I just installed a fresh copy of weblogic server and OSB.
After the successful installation of weblogic 10.3.6 on the quick start screen I tried to configure domain. however the screen doesn't processed any further giving the error in the screenshot below.

[image]

Also, in eclipse, when i try to add the server, It prompts me to create a domain, but that doesn't work either.
The error am getting in the console is:

```
 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option 
 MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
 Unrecognized VM option 'UseSpinning'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Java 8 is being picked up elsewhere on your system.

Check to see if you have Java 8 installed and look at you path environment variable.

That warning you are getting is from Java 8. 10.3.6 would use Java 5 or 6...

Comment: this is correct. 10.3.6 will support up to java 6. You should look for a JRockit 1.6 SDK in the oracle webpage

Comment: @mkane , Thanks. First of all, am confirmed that Java 8 has been installaed and environment variables are have been added (JAVA_HOME). Moreover, I was allowed to only add environment variable for my user account not for the system variables, I don't think this is an issue. Also, I have seen other successful installations for webogic 10.3.6 and Java 8